# Why compilation error when accessing private members of the same class

Tags: c++

Why this program giving compilation error:

proxy.cpp: In member function ‘void ProxyCar::MoveCar()’:
proxy.cpp:59: error: ‘int Driver::age’ is private
proxy.cpp:81: error: within this context

```
class Car
{
    public:
        void MoveCar()
        {
                cout << "Car has been driven";
        }
};

class Driver
{
    private:
         int age;

    public:

        int get() { return age; }
        void set(int value) { age = value; }
        Driver(int age):age(age){}
};

class ProxyCar
{
    private:
        Driver driver;
        Car *realCar;

    public:
    ProxyCar(Driver driver): driver(driver), realCar (new Car) {}

    void MoveCar()
    {
        if (driver.age <= 16)
          cout << "Sorry the driver is too young to drive";
        else
            realCar->MoveCar();
    }
};

int main()
{
        Driver d(16);
        ProxyCar p(d);
        p.MoveCar();
        return 0;
}
```

I am trying to access the Driver object inside ProxyCar. This line is causing the error.
 if (driver.age <= 16)

Comment: ProxyCar and Driver are different classes. Only Driver objects are allowed to access private members of Driver.

Answer (score 4):

Because `age` is a private member in the `Driver` class.

Do you intent to do this:

```
     if (driver.get()<= 16)
         cout << "Sorry the driver is too young to drive";
     else
         realCar->MoveCar();
```

Answer (score 3):

`Driver::age` is a `private` member of `class Driver`. Hence, it is only accessible to the members of `class Driver`

However, you may use accessor methods to let the outside world access the `private` members.

```
class Driver
{
    private:
        int age;

    public:
        int get_age() { return age; }
};
```

And use the accessor method to get the `private` members of the class.

```
if (driver.get_age() <= 16)
    cout << "Sorry the driver is too young to drive";
else
    realCar->MoveCar();
```

For more on access modifiers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_modifiers

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a private member of `Driver`. This is a separate class and you have no visibility to its private members.